# android studio generates invalid 9 patch png

Tags: android, nine-patch

I stuck on generating 9 patch png with android studio's tool.Here what I do:

1. Right click on png(progress.png) and select create 9 patch
2. Set its name to _progress.9.png
3. Mark stretchable areas(see screenshot)
4. rebuild the project

In the end I got gradle error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Cleaning project and invalidating cache doesn't help.Here how it looks like:
[image: 9 patch png]
Is android studio can't generate valid 9 patches?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Gradle` Console to know what the issue is,

See ScreenShot

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: here what I got in the gradle console:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: @undefined Please look at my pic again, the error details are in described at the `AAPT` part, search for that part at your `Gradle` console then use these details to solve your problem

Comment: there is no such section.Here what I see in the console:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68778662/gradle%20error.png

Comment: the problem was that I have to set stretchable regions explicitly from all 4 sides although in the spec its said:
` If the padding lines are not included, Android uses the left and top lines to define this drawable area.`